# PSExcel Export-XLSX adding extra columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell

Once a month I run a PS script to export some client data from a MSSQL database to an Excel spreadsheet.  I've made some big tweaks to the query for this month and the data returned is fine (when I run it in Management Studio), and when I run the PS script that creates the Excel file, it also runs fine.

The problem is that when I go to open the Excel file, there is an error message stating

> We found a problem with some content in *file.xlsx*. Do you want us
>   to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of the
>   workbook, click Yes.

I click yes and then the file opens with a repairs report saying that it repaired Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml.  All data I need is there, so I'm not too concerned about that (I would like to fix it though).  My issue is that in addition to the columns I specified in my query, there is five extra columns:

1. RowError
2. RowState
3. Table
4. ItemArray
5. HasErrors

How do I stop these appearing in my Excel file?

My PS script consists of:

```
# -- START SETUP

$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator 

if ($myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
   {
   $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "(Elevated)"
   $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
   clear-host
   }
else
   {

   $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell";   

   $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;   

   $newProcess.Verb = "runas";

   [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);

   exit
   }

Import-Module C:\scripts-and-reports\Modules\PSExcel
Import-Module SQLPS

# -- END SETUP :: START EXPORT

invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\scripts-and-reports\all_new-matters-since-last-run.sql" -serverinstance "2012R2-PE-SVR\PRACTICEEVOLVE" -database "PracticeEvolve_c1" | 
    Export-XLSX -WorksheetName "15-05-2017 to $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)" -Path "C:\scripts-and-reports\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd) Tamworth PE client report since 15-05-2017.xlsx" -Table -Force -Verbose

Write-Host -NoNewLine "Export and report creation complete!  Press any key to continue..."

$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

# -- END EXPORT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are properties from `Invoke-SQLCMD` results. You would not see them displayed via standard output because they are not selected as part of the default property set for that cmdlet. In the same way that `Get-ChildItem` does not show you all of a files/folders properties by default. They still exist however so if you do not want them in the Excel you need to exclude them

```
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\scripts-and-reports\all_new-matters-since-last-run.sql" -serverinstance "2012R2-PE-SVR\PRACTICEEVOLVE" -database "PracticeEvolve_c1" | 
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty  "RowError","RowState","Table","ItemArray","HasErrors" | 
    Export-XLSX -WorksheetName "15-05-2017 to $(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)" -Path "C:\scripts-and-reports\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd) Tamworth PE client report since 15-05-2017.xlsx" -Table -Force -Verbose
```

The effectively will return all properties except the ones you are not looking for. This is useful when you don't know the properties of the dataset you are returning. Else you could just use a exclusive list like `Select-Object Name,Length,Bagel`

Comment: Perfect!  this was exactly what I was looking for.
I found that the error message on XLSX open was caused by the -table parameter... removing that and the file opened fine (but was missing its Table style formatting).